# WCF Fault InvalidSecurity due to time differences

Tags: wcf, time, difference

I have encountered an error that occurs due to different time between client and server. The communication is secured and thus the error occurs at the System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityToken DoNegotiation(System.TimeSpan) call (as of targetSite).

I can reproduce this error by simply changing the client's computer time.

Is there a possibility to exactly detect this case?

Should I do a time check by myself?

Or should I prepare an error message pointing to the time differences as a possible cause?

Thanks, Lothar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The secured channel is encrypted with PKI plus the timestamp, and the default skew is 5 minutes. That is, the different between client and server should not be more than 5 minutes. For more details how this works, google "wcf clock skew".

Windows since Win2k had come with built-in feature to sync clock with a NTP server, so make sure such feature is turned on in both server and client.

Generally business applications should not check the accuracy of the clock, since the accuracy is system issue which many networking functions could depend on. If the system environment is not healthy, many other applications in the same machine will fail as well. System issue should be resolved through the system way, in this case, make sure the clock is accurate through the built-in time sync function of Windows.

Comment: Yes, but I like to get a plausible cause for the failure. Thus I checked the system time to decide reporting such a possibility to my user. For a service, there may be a log message produced. I do not intent to change the time in that case.

Comment: Firstly as hinted in the answer, it is a bit illogical for a business application or web service/client to take care of such system issue; secondly because NTP has much shorter timeout by design and higher failure rates of connecting to a NTP server because of network jam or time server too busy, it is not worthy to introduce extra complexity and inevitable unreliability into your program. Ensuring accurate clock is much cheaper and simpler than other approaches.

Comment: I suppose you sell reliability to your customers, not the smarty of identifying different causes of connection failures. Ensuring the clock accuracy could remove the needs of detecting, logging and reporting such cause of connection failure, while there could be hundreds of causes.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Then I worry about Windows 8.1, not getting this done right when a tablet wakes up from sleep. That is actually my problem when testing my app on such a device.

Comment: but if the clock of the tablet become shifting for up to 5 minutes after a few days or a few weeks, that tablet is really poor. After a few weeks, the battery die anyway. I am sure about Win8 tablet, at least for iPad and Android devices, when sleeping, some background processes are still running, like the time sync function.

Comment: Yes, it is a cheap tablet. I'll simply bought it for testing purposes :-)